# When using (substack's) Tape module for testing, how do I run only one test in a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, tap, node.js-tape

When using [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) how do I run a specific test and ignore all other tests?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[**According to the docs:**](https://github.com/substack/tape#testonlyname-cb) Change that test's code from `test(//etc)` to `test.only(//etc)`. It will be the only test run for that process.

Otherwise, you can put a certain test or tests in a separate file and just run that file alone.